# Is the smallest algebra containing a collection always within the smallest sigma algebra containing that collection?

Tags: measure-theory

There are many questions here about algebras and sigma algebras, but none seem to ask quite what I'm after.

---

Say we have a whole set $S$, and any collection of subsets $\mathscr{S} \subset 2^S$.

Elementary measure theory that there exists a smallest algebra containing $\mathscr{S}$, and we call it $\alpha(\mathscr{S})$.

We also know that there exists a smallest sigma algebra containing $\mathscr{S}$, and we call it $\sigma(\mathscr{S})$.

That is,

$$
\mathscr{S} \subseteq \alpha(\mathscr{S}) \\
\mathscr{S} \subseteq \sigma(\mathscr{S}) \\
$$

And we also know that the sigma algebra contains the algebra.

$$
\alpha(\mathscr{S}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathscr{S})
$$

But one can also generate a sigma algebra from the algebra, denoted $\sigma(\alpha(\mathscr{S}))$.

---

My intuition is that the latter sigma algebra contains the former,

$$
\sigma(\mathscr{S}) \subseteq \sigma(\alpha(\mathscr{S}))
$$

Indeed, I suspect that they are equivalent:

$$
\sigma(\mathscr{S}) = \sigma(\alpha(\mathscr{S}))
$$

But I'm having trouble showing or disproving both relationships.  Either way, I suspect it's really simple.  Is anyone able to help?

Comment: Yes, by necessity, since any $\sigma$ algebra containing $\alpha(S)$ contains $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any sigma algebra is an algebra. Hence the smallest algebra containing  a collection is necessarily contained in the smallest sigma algebra containing  the collection.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response.  Sorry if this is really obvious, but would you be able to explain why the second sentence holds?  "_Hence the smallest algebra containing a collection is necessarily contained in the smallest sigma algebra containing the collection._"

Comment: @kdbanman It is just the meaning of the word .smallest. The smallest algebra containing a given family is contained in any other algebra containing the given family.

Comment: Ah, that helped cement it for me - I did not realize that was the case.  I guess we are fortunate that such "smallest" algebras and sigma algebras exist!  Thanks again.